# ServiceStack's fluent validation does not work with the Equals function

Tags: servicestack

This snipped works fine:

```
RuleFor(request => request.Id)
      .Must(id => id == 0)
      .WithMessage("'Id' must be equal to '0'.");
```

And this one doesn't work (it's just ignored):

```
RuleFor(request => request.Id)
      .Equals(0)
      .WithMessage("'Id' must be equal to '0'."));
```

Am I missing something or is the **Equals** function erroneous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [FluentValidation API for Equals](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Validators) is `Equal`, i.e:

```
RuleFor(request => request.Id)
      .Equal(0)
      .WithMessage("'Id' must be equal to '0'."));
```

Calling `Equals` just calls `Object.Equals()` which doesn't register a validator.